# Android installing apk to device gives [SEGMENTATION FAULT]

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-studio

i have a problem. When i am trying to deploy (Debug or Run) my App with the AndroidStudio, i get the following error in the RunLog

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-galaxy_nexus-WOVCBUF6BAGENRTO
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Abracadabra\Desktop\......\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/xxx.xxx.app
Installing xxx.xxx.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/xxx.xxx.app"

Segmentation fault
```

It works fine when i try to deploy it to the genymotion VM. It just does not work on my real device. It did work before, but i have cleaned up some folders there with the rootExplorer, for example i deleted a folder called ".Idea". Maybe this was a big mistake?
Is this the reason why it does not work anymore?

By the way, logcat is working fine for the rest of the phone.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. I also installed a fresh android with the CWM recovery tool and wiped all user and cache data -> did not help.

P.P.S I found out, that the apk is in /data/local/tmp on the phone. I can install it manually with the rootExplorer. but debugging is also not possible :/

P.P.P.S: I also have tried "adb install", also gives me segmentation fault.

It seems that copy is possible, but installation not.

Comment: I was able to work-around the problem by using `pm install <packageName>` running as root on the tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the reason. (a quite stupid one)

I forgot to enable "Security Settings -> Unknown Sources"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_n7100-4df180b77e139fdd
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Harshal\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\CurrentAffairs\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.softcode.anupreet.currentaffairs
Installing com.softcode.anupreet.currentaffairs
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.softcode.anupreet.currentaffairs"
Segmentation fault
```

I downloaded the 'Terminal Emulator' app on my device and ran the below two commands, it was a success.

```
su -o pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.softcode.anupreet.currentaffairs"
```