# Android studio: Segmentation fault while trying to deploy app on Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, segmentation-fault

I am getting `Segmentation fault` when I try to run my app from `Android Studio`. I have tried to restart the device, Android Studio and even my PC.

This is what I get! How can I solve this

```
Installing APK: F:\......\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.astrolabe.mofa
Installing com.astrolabe.mofa
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.astrolabe.mofa"
Segmentation fault 


Launching application: com.astrolabe.mofa/com.astrolabe.mofa.FullscreenActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "com.astrolabe.mofa/com.astrolabe.mofa.FullscreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Segmentation fault
```

**EDIT**

This Question is not Duplicate of the one pointed out as the solution to that problem will not fix my issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android installing apk to device gives \[SEGMENTATION FAULT\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245986/android-installing-apk-to-device-gives-segmentation-fault)

Comment: @LinX64 Thanks for pointing out but I am not able to solve my issue. Possibly its not the same cause!

Comment: Have you tried that with adb ? `pm install <packageName>` and make sure your device's Usb debugging is enabled or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this option is enabled or not(*That should be enabled*):

`Security Settings -> Unknown Sources`.

**Update:**

Also make sure you've enabled **Usb debugging** on your phone.

Or, try to install that app with the following command via `adb` and see if it is installing or not:

```
pm install <packageName>
```

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Developer options -> Verify apps over USB

disable it.

may be visible only when ADB debugging is enabled and phone is connected to computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly was causing the issue. I had enabled `USB debugging` as well as install from `Unknown Sources` as suggested, but that even couldn't solve the issue.

Doing a factory reset of the device did solve my problem. I am sure this is not the solution and there might be a better solution for this.